# NSURLConnection Download Progress

Tags: ios, download, nsurlconnection, progress

I am trying to show the progress of a download from an API, but NSURLConnectionDelegate does not have a total bytes value anywhere. Is there some way to get the total amount of bytes that I am downloading before it finishes the download?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get expected contents length from NSURLResponse via `-expectedContentLength` method. For example if you use `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate` you can obtain that information in delegate's  `connection:didReceiveResponse:` method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    ...
    long long contentLength = [response expectedContentLength];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats great! Does NSURLResponseUnknownLength come up very often? But hopefully this works out!

Comment: @RileyE sorry, don't know about NSURLResponseUnknownLength... But since I never seen that might mean that it is rather rare :)